# Upgrade to Oracle 11g to 19c

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, obiee, oracle19c

We are using a legacy app OBIEE 11.1.7 app. We are currently using a 11g database and would like to upgrade to 19c. Is 11.1.7 obiee version compatible with 19c? What do I need to do? Do i need to install any drivers?

Since currently, there is no 19c available in my database type . Can I just use the Oracle 11g instead? This is the default value.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yffoc.jpg)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will work since a data source is just a data source and the type specification defines how they queries are written - and 19c is able to understand 11g SQL with no issue. But you really should upgrade your OBI since it is 9 major releases behind what's current. Your 11.1.1.7 is out of support since December 2018.

Comment: As per checking on the certification matrix. OBIEE version 11.1.1.7.0 does not support 19c database. But this certification matrix is as of 2014.

Do you have any idea if its still supported?

Thanks!

Comment: If In your original question you're talking abou tusing 19c as a data source. The certification matrix talks about the RCU. Those are two completely different things.